# Can I use a conditional panel to only display data if the sysDate() falls between two dates?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am constructing a shiny app for tracking salmonid spawning runs. I have constructed the app to work for some species that are currently running, but the way my exterior query is set up, it cannot construct tables and graphs unless a fish has been collected in the 2020 season. For these species that have not began their runs yet, I want to display last years tables and graphs. Is there a way in Shiny to have a conditional panel reference sysDate() or, even better, the raw r code so it can correctly determine whether to plot 2020 data or 2019 data?

As an example. Coho do not begin running until August and their run continues until the following February. If the end user looks at the app between those months, I want it to display the current daily data. However, if the end user looks at the app outside of those months, I want it to display last year's data with a not that reads "The 2020 run has not began yet."

```
ui <- tabsetPanel(id="species",
    tabPanel(id = "co", title = "Coho",
             selectInput("coho_origin_select",label = h3("Select origin"),
                         choices = list("Hatchery", "Wild"), 
                         selected = "Hatchery"),
             fluidRow(
                 column(4, offset = 1, plotOutput("co_curvePlot2020")),
                 column(4, offset = 1, plotOutput("co_dailyPlot2020"))),
             formattableOutput("co_table2020"))

server <- function(input, output) {
output$co_dailyPlot2020 <- renderPlot({
    if(input$co_origin_select =="Hatchery") {print(co_daily_plot_AD2020)}
    if(input$co_origin_select =="Wild") {print(co_daily_plot_UM2020)}
})
output$co_curvePlot2020 <- renderPlot({
    if(input$co_origin_select =="Hatchery") {print(co__ad_plot2020)}
    if(input$co_origin_select =="Wild") {print(co__um_plot2020)}
})
output$co_table2020 <- renderFormattable({
    if(input$co_origin_select =="Hatchery") ({formattable(co_table_ad2020)})
    else if(input$co_origin_select =="Wild") ({formattable(co_table_um2020)})
})
```

Ideally the final server side would output co_dailyPlot2020, co_curvePlot2020 and co_table2020 if the user looks at the app between August 2020 and February 2021 and if they view it prior to August 2020 it would print co_dailyPlot2019, co_curvePlot2019 and co_table2019 instead.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. If you can supply some shiny app code that can be modified, I'm sure you'd find help if you had a specific problem.

Comment: @cory I think that should be sufficient code to make some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same `output$co_dailyPlot` etc. and inside the `render` determine which data to use. For this, I created a boolean variable that depends on the date. Note that your conditions are not completely clear (what to do after 2021/02?), so it is just `TRUE` for 2020/08 - 2021/02:

```
ui <- tabsetPanel(id="species",
                  tabPanel(id = "co", title = "Coho",
                           selectInput("coho_origin_select",label = h3("Select origin"),
                                       choices = list("Hatchery", "Wild"), 
                                       selected = "Hatchery"),
                           fluidRow(
                             column(4, offset = 1, plotOutput("co_curvePlot")),
                             column(4, offset = 1, plotOutput("co_dailyPlot"))),
                           formattableOutput("co_table"))
                  
                  server <- function(input, output) {
                    
                    show_2020_data <- 
                      (as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%m")) >= 8 &&
                         as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")) == 2020) ||
                      (as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%m")) <= 2 &&
                         as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")) == 2021)
                    
                    output$co_dailyPlot <- renderPlot({
                      if (show_2020_data) {
                        if(input$co_origin_select =="Hatchery") {print(co_daily_plot_AD2020)}
                        if(input$co_origin_select =="Wild") {print(co_daily_plot_UM2020)}
                      } else {
                        # old plots
                      }
                      
                    })
                    output$co_curvePlot <- renderPlot({
                      if (show_2020_data) {
                        if(input$co_origin_select =="Hatchery") {print(co__ad_plot2020)}
                        if(input$co_origin_select =="Wild") {print(co__um_plot2020)}
                      } else {
                        # old plots
                      }
                    })
                    output$co_table <- renderFormattable({
                      if (show_2020_data) {
                        if(input$co_origin_select =="Hatchery") ({formattable(co_table_ad2020)})
                        else if(input$co_origin_select =="Wild") ({formattable(co_table_um2020)})
                      } else {
                        # old plots
                      }
                    })
```

Comment: @straja Could I instead use     

show_present_data <- 
        (as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%m")) >= 8) ||
        (as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%m")) <= 2)

That would be the same for each year then because the run months are pretty uniform year to year

Comment: If you make sure that the present data matches the data you want to show (e.g. in February 2021 the present data is from 2020 and in August 2021 the present data is from 2021), sure this is an option. You can use what fits your needs/how you store the data